# Multiplying by indexes position in 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Being fairly new to Java I have a quick question and haven't seen it here. I have 2 Array lists, and I need to multiply the numbers held in the index position in each list by each other to provide the answer, 
    e.g. 
    ArrayListAlpha(0,1,2,3 etc)
    ArrayListBeta(0,1,2,3 etc)

```
So I need to multiply 1x1, 2x2, 3x3 etc. and then display the answers onscreen in a descending order; I also need to show the calculation and the information in the arrays.
e.g.
1x1 = 
2x2 = 
3x3 = 

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks
```

Comment: fyi, folks are probably marking down your question because you haven't shown any effort in solving it.  try taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a very simpel way is:

```
for(int i=0 ;i<ArrayListAlpha.size();i++){
            System.out.println(i+"x"+i+" = "+ArrayListAlpha.get(i)*ArrayListBeta.get(i));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI this is not an "I give you a result answer"...

You could have solved your issue easily using google or so...

Anyways you might look up Java API's ["ArrayList"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) documentation page.
There you'll find `get(int index);`

Then take a `for`-loop and you are done.